# Client/server username/password authentication

Tags: java, sockets

I am working on a Client/server authentication program, but I ran into a problem. The client makes the server connection fine, but once I type in my password and username it doesn't return whether it's a valid username/password.  If the user logins in with right username/password server is supposed to return "Welcome, username" and if it's invalid it returns "failed to login". I have looked at the printwriter and bufferedreader docs to make sure that I am using the right methods to pass the text between server/client properly. I tried debugging by printing the username and password on both the server and client to make sure that they are both listening/writing, which they seem to be, because it does print out the proper username/password. Can someone give me some insight on where I am going wrong?

```
public class Connect {
    private String USERNAME = "java";
    private String PASSWORD = "java";
    private int PORT = 9090;
    private String HOSTNAME = "localhost";

    public String getUsername(){
        return this.USERNAME;
    }

    public String getPassword(){

        return this.PASSWORD;
    }

    public int getPort(){
        return this.PORT;
    }

    public String gethostName(){
        return this.HOSTNAME;
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.net.*;
public class Client {
    private final String FILENAME = null;
    Connect c = new Connect();
    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader read;
    PrintWriter output;

    public void startClient() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
        //Create socket connection
        socket = new Socket(c.gethostName(), c.getPort());

        //create printwriter for sending login to server
        output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

        //prompt for user name
        String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Name:");

        //send user name to server
        output.println(username);

        //prompt for password
        String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Password");

        //send password to server
        output.println(password);
        output.flush();

        //create Buffered reader for reading response from server
        read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        //read response from server
        String response = read.readLine();
        System.out.println("This is the response: " + response);

        //display response
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, response);
    }

    public void fileInfo(){

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Client client = new Client();
        try {
            client.startClient();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.net.*;
public class Server {
    private int currentTot;
    ServerSocket serversocket;
    Socket client;
    int bytesRead;
    Connect c = new Connect();
    BufferedReader input;
    PrintWriter output;

    public void start() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Connection Starting on port:" + c.getPort());
        //make connection to client on port specified
        serversocket = new ServerSocket(c.getPort());

        //accept connection from client
        client = serversocket.accept();

        System.out.println("Waiting for connection from client");

        try {
            logInfo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void logInfo() throws Exception{
        //open buffered reader for reading data from client
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

        String username = input.readLine();
        System.out.println("SERVER SIDE" + username);
        String password = input.readLine();
        System.out.println("SERVER SIDE" + password);

        //open printwriter for writing data to client
        output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));

        if(username.equals(c.getUsername()) &&password.equals(c.getPassword())){
            output.println("Welcome, " + username);
        }else{
            output.println("Login Failed");
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Server server = new Server();
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Can you post the Server and Client code? Without seeing how they're implemented we can't really do much.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the scroll bar! My bad

Comment: Does the server side print out the username and password when it receives it?

Comment: Yes, it prints out, but it's not until after I abort the program. I used that print statement on the server to see if what was receiving username/password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to flush the printWriter of the server just like you are doing on the client side.

At the end of your `loginfo()` method,

```
if(username.equals(c.getUsername()) &&password.equals(c.getPassword())){
    output.println("Welcome, " + username);
}else{
    output.println("Login Failed");
}
output.flush();
output.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate against plaintext String within the code, use a conditional to check if the username and password are valid.

However, if you want to pretend we're in the real world, authenticate against LDAP or at least an encrypted properties file...

```
Hashtable ldap = new Hashtable(11);
ldap.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
ldap.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ldapserver:389/o=OU");
input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
String username = input.readLine();
String password = input.readLine();
ldap.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "tls");
ldap.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=" + username + ", ou=OU1, o=OU2");
ldap.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

try {
    DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(ldap);
    context.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none");
    context.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.toString();
    }
 }
```

> Courtesy of oracle docs...